# Gnome not working well with NoMachine

Tags: ubuntu, gnome, themes, nomachine

First of all, NoMachine is working for me.  However, at some point with my Ubuntu/Gnome machine, I got an update for Gnome and now when running NoMachine I no longer get all of the theme elements.  For example the panels are there but with the default or stock colors.  This is true for the icons as well.  Does anybody know a solution for this problem?

Comment: have you rebooted since installing your updates?  (or at least completely stopped/restarted NoMachine?)

Comment: @quack - Yes, many times.

Comment: Mine has this problem, too.  I've just been ignoring it.  I'm using the FreeNX repository https://launchpad.net/~freenx-team/+archive/ppa

Comment: Was hoping this would be fixed in 9.10, it is not.

Comment: I was having trouble with my Gnome/GTK+ applications not drawing/painting through NoMachine.  This happened after my session had been working fine for several days.  I didn't root-cause it, but this question led me to a usable solution (that didn't involve restarting).  I found that the "Mist" theme had no problems, but all of the other installed themes failed to draw correctly.  This was under Red Hat 6.6 with GNOME 2.28.2.

Answer (score 2):

I know that this question is very old, but the issue persists and maybe someone lands here in a Google Search. The problem is that gconf crashes con login, and here is the solution:

Run `gconf-editor`, use Alt-F2 or the terminal.
Go to `/apps/gnome_settings_daemon/plugins/keyboard`.
Uncheck the "Active" box on the right.
Select any theme you want, and you're done!

Comment: thanks for the answer; you're right about the search possibilities.  can you expand this a little, to explain what this is changing and why the change works?